# TikTok Oauth - Parameter error (Login kit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, tiktok

I am trying to login to my app using tiktok (login kit). I have created a web based app in Tiktok. provided correct redirect domain. App is 'Live in Production'.

I am able to redirect to `titok.com` but when I click on the authorize option, I am getting below error,

`{"data":{"description":"Parameter error. Please ensure there are no unnecessary parameters in query or payload.","error_code":10002,"captcha":"","desc_url":""},"message":"error"}`

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Rita

I tried to connect to login with tiktok credentials,
I am using omniauth-tiktok gem. below is the config

```
provider :tiktok, "<<Client ID>>", "<<Client Secret>>",
            scope: "user.info.basic",
            token_params: { parse: :json }
```

I was expecting to fetch user info and video list.

Comment: Did you debug and check the submitted data when you click on login with TikTok and compare with https://github.com/Lianowar/omniauth-tiktok#auth-hash ?

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR.

We have build a fork of the strategy you use for making it work, see
[our github repo](https://github.com/lasercatspro/omniauth-tiktok)

### Tiktok doesn't respect OAuth2 protocol

#### Note

This error take place during the authorization phase of OAuth2 protocol, for more info see section [**4.1 Authorization Grant**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1), from the oauth2 doc.

#### Find and manage the error

The error from Tiktok is due to bad implementation of OAuth2 protocol. OAuth2 protocol specify that, when you provide connection with other services you need an identifier, also named client identifier.

> 2.2.  Client Identifier
>
> The authorization server issues the registered client a client
> identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
> information provided by the client.  The client identifier is not a
> secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
> alone for client authentication.  The client identifier is unique to
> the authorization server.

This client identifier, client_id, is **required**, as specified in the 2.3.1 section of the protocol. You can see more at [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

Has you may begin to understand, Tiktok doesn't use client_id for authenticate user through OAuth2 protocol, as it said in the [doc](https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/login-kit-manage-user-access-tokens/) for fetching user access token.
If we look closer to needed parameters to retrieve an `access_token` we do not see "client_id".
[the needed parameters from the tiktok api doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOrr1.png)

The problem is, as `client_id` is a required parameter in the protocol, the ruby gem oauth2 manage the **authorization phase** by automatically send the client_id to Tiktok. Tiktok doesn't manage client_id, so it sends back a parameter error saying that there is *unnecessary parameters in query*.

This is why you need to modify OAuth client configuration in order to "not respect the protocol", from the omniauth strategy itself, which is a bad thing. But as we had to find a solution, we forked the original omniauth-tiktok gem to add 2 things that allow to not send client_id to Tiktok:

- A `client_options: { auth_scheme: :basic_auth }`, to bypass `OAuth2::Authenticator`'s `apply` method that automatically add client_id.
- A custom `build_access_token` method, that replaces `redirect_uri` (that was also not needed) with `client_secret` to have the right parameters sent to Tiktok.

#### Other solutions

This is our solutions, but when we where looking at it, we found other possibilities.

1. We found that omniauth-tiktok 1.0.0 and omniauth 2.1.0 was using OAuth 1.4.4 version, in the last version of OAuth you can add a block to a `get_token` call. This block is executed just before sending the `access_token` request, so it is possible with the last version of OAuth2 gem to execute code block that correct parameters before sending request to tiktok.
2. We tried to monkeypatch `OAuth2::Authenticator`'s `apply`method, that automaticaly add `client_id` and it worked, but we preferred the method described above because it has no consequences for other pieces of code.

##### UPDATE of 08/09/2023

We'v migrated the old API using a fork by [acorn-influence](https://github.com/acorn-influence/omniauth-tiktok). Since Tiktok change their API, they put more restricted way of reading params during the OAuth callback phase.
We modify our way to get rid of "client_id" by monkey patch OAuth2::Authenticator's method `apply(params)`. This monkey patch had a special auth_scheme for tiktok that doesnt send `client_id`.

We'v tested out by authenticate through other omniauth-strategies and it seems to work, but as we all know **monkey patch can be dangereous and cause bugs**.